# Ignore package target path when using grunt-bower

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I'm experimenting with grunt/bower for a project and I have the following content structure:

```
content 
    css
    js
```

I've got grunt/bower working on my own files, but I'm trying to incorporate jquery now and the bower task keeps putting jquery in `content/js/dist/jquery.js` where I'd rather have `content/js/jquery.js`.  In other words, I want to strip / ignore the `dist` folder when copying the file. So far, my task looks like this:

```
    bower: {
        install: {},
        dev: {
            dest: 'Content',
            js_dest: 'Content/js',
            less_dest: 'Content/css',
            css_dest: 'Content/css',
            options: {
                packageSpecific: {
                    "jquery": {
                        dest: 'Content/js'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

How can I tell the bower task to copy the `dist/jquery.js` from the jquery package file to the specific path `content/js/jquery.js` in my app?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with Bower since the jQuery bower package file specifies what file to copy: `"main": "dist/jquery.js"`. In other words, their package specifies the final folder location. You could add a [Grunt copy task](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy) afterward if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *keepExpandedHierarchy* option (flattened output structure) in order to achieve this behavior. You can set is specifically on for jquery:

```
bower: {
    install: {},
    dev: {
        dest: 'Content',
        js_dest: 'Content/js',
        less_dest: 'Content/css',
        css_dest: 'Content/css',
        options: {
            packageSpecific: {
                'jquery': {
                  keepExpandedHierarchy: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running grunt bower the jquery.js file is copied to Content\js\jquery.js:

```
>grunt bower
Running "bower:install" (bower) task

Running "bower:dev" (bower) task
Content\js\jquery.js copied.

Done, without errors.
```